# TALEND - tmap component default Date

Tags: talend

I am using a tMap component. I have a date field with default pattern as "dd-MM-yyyy". I just need to insert a Blank Value. i tried '01-01-1900',"",TalendDate.getCurrentDate() : However they gave errors.

Is there a way to could only insert 01-01-1900  or a Null Value with datatype as DATE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try TalendDate.parseDate() function...

Answer (score 1):

you can simply either type null in expression in tmap or use TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", "1900-01-01")

Comment: Thank you for the Answers. i used the TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", "1900-01-01"), it worked good,